# Clarification of notation related to law of indices for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am new to abstract algebra. While reading a text on ring theory,a part of the law of indices was stated as : 
for all $a,b$ belonging to a Ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ ; $a^m \cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.
Since $+$ and $\cdot$ could be any binary operations satisfying the definition of a ring and hence possibly different from addition and multiplication, I wish to know to know if the $+$ in $a^{m+n}$ refers to any such binary operation or just addition. I think that this should generally be true only for addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $+$ in $a^{m+n}$ is the addition in $\mathbb N$.

The $\cdot$ in $a^m \cdot a^n = a^{m+n}$ is the multiplication in the ring $R$.